# Singleton in ES6 not persisting instance

Tags: javascript

This was close, but, it kept creating the instance over and over on every call of this module because I think the variable was in a new function constructor every time:

```
export const DB = () => {
    const dbInstance;

    function getInstance() {
        if (!dbInstance) {
            const db = newDb();
            db.public.none(fs.readFileSync('src/DB/migrations/001-initial.sql', 'utf8'));
            dbInstance = db;
        }
        return dbInstance;
    }
    return {
        getInstance,
    };
};

export default DB;
```

I moved `dbInstance` out, it works, but, feels dirty because I know `dbInstance` is not encapsulated and still accessible to consumers, they could import that still:

```js
let dbInstance;

export const DB = () => {
    function getInstance() {
        if (!dbInstance) {
            const db = newDb();
            db.public.none(fs.readFileSync('src/DB/migrations/001-initial.sql', 'utf8'));
            dbInstance = db;
        }
        return dbInstance;
    }
    return {
        getInstance,
    };
};

export default DB;
```

So, how would I properly do the first example, and fix it without my hack, basically?

Comment: I don't think that it is accessible to consumers. Only exported vars/functions are accessible. Have a go at trying to access it and tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: Speaking of, you don't need to export DB twice.

Comment: There is no need to fix anything because it is not dirty. All properly declared variables in modules have file scope and are not accessible outside the file. In any case, you're doing it wrong. ES6 modules are singletons thus there is no need to implement the singleton pattern that other lesser languages require.

Comment: No, I did need a singleton in terms of only creating the DB instance once, in that regard.  I'm not talking ES6 module singletons.  I know they are singletons by nature.  I'm sharing the instance of the DB here AND the es6 module is being shared so when i say singleton, I mean both levels there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 modules, just like CommonJS modules, are singletons. Thus the simplest and **correct** way to implement a singleton in ES6 is:

```
const db = newDb();
db.public.none(fs.readFileSync('src/DB/migrations/001-initial.sql', 'utf8'));

export default db;
```

Comment: I thought every time `db` is imported to another file it would run all code in the imported file, hence `const db` would be called and then create a new instance of newDB() every time it's imported into another file.  But maybe I thought wrong

Comment: In other languages yes. That's how imports normally work. In javascript since node.js (maybe even before) modules have been implemented as singletons. For node.js it was probably an accidental side effect of the module caching logic which in the end behaves exactly like actual singletons. ES6 follows this tradition because it reduces memory usage and developers are used to the behavior

Comment: yea but when is newDB() called, once on import at comnpile time? or when code tries to use the exported db variable (lazily calling newDb() during runtime)?  In other words yes this is a singleton module but inside it, its state, how you create internal variables, in this case, is newDb() being called when?

Comment: You cannot call a function or evaluate an expression at compile time. Thus **any** call happens at runtime. The first time the module is imported it is evaluated which means `newDB` is called. The next time the module is imported is is not evaluated again (none of the code in the module run more than once unless you manually call exported functions more than once) and the module returns the cached version. However you imagine singletons work the entire contents of the module (inside functions, inside classes, outside functions etc) work the same way you think singletons work

Comment: I appreciate your last comment, thanks for being detailed!